# How to execute the Durandal JS optimizer.exe as part of VS2012 build/publish process?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, release-management, single-page-application, durandal

I was getting 404 Not found for the main-built.js file when I was running my DurandalJS SPA application published in release mode on a web server.

[image: 404 Not Found: main-built.js]

So I figured out I needed to run the optimizer.exe to generete the missing file main-built.js

Is it possible to include the execution of optimizer.exe as part of Visual Studio 2012 build/publish process? 
If yes, how do I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I added the optimizer step as a Pre Build step.

So in the Pre Build Events box in the project properties of your web project I added this:

```
cd $(ProjectDir)App\durandal\amd

optimizer.exe
```

main-built.js is then generated as part of the build process.

Note you will probably have to add the main-built.js file to your project for it to be deployed automatically if you are using msdeploy. I had to do this because we are using TFS hosted build service with automatic Azure publishing. Without this step the file was not being deployed.

Comment: @Blaise you have to install Node.js for the optimizer to work... see http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Optimizing-On-Dot-Net/

Comment: You only need Node.js to run the optimizer.exe correct? Basically I'm wondering if I need Node.js on the server as well

Comment: Yes just to run the optimizer. You would need it on your build server too, but not your production server.

Comment: Cheers Alex. It turned out to be easier to search Stack Overflow than to come upstairs and ask you :)

Comment: @Sohape The new link for .NET documentation is http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Automating-Builds-with-Visual-Studio.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did:

Place these lines of code into `Post Build Events`

```
cd $(ProjectDir)App\durandal\amd
optimizer.exe
```

The `main-built.js` will be created under `\App` after the solution is built but it is not included in the project. I then select `Show All Files` and include the file.

Then the `main-built.js` will be available every time I publish the web app in the future.

Comment: Is the only thing you have done differently is doing this step on Post Build rather than Pre Build?

Comment: I have no `node.js`. Just move your code to `Post Build` and manually include the `main-built.js` into the project.

Comment: I indicated that you'll need to add main-built.js to the project. So are you saying that it didn't work on pre build but did work on post build for you? Any idea why?